# Pdf Markdown table vertical line

Tags: r, markdown

Is it possible to draw a vertical line between columns in pdf Markdown table? I am going to separate each column and make a table like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the `xtable` package, see `5.2 Column alignment` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having a reproducible answer available:

```
library(xtable)
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:10, ])
align(tli.table) <- "|rrl|l|lr|"
tli.table
```

Of course, for more details do check out the xtable document in George Dontas' response.